# Why do we need to write the noise as randn(2,1)./sqrt(2*SNR) instead of randn(1,1)/sqrt(2)?

Tags: noise, digital-communications

I saw this code, about the error probability of on/off signal ,on the internet

```
Ts=10^4;
SNR_dB=[-3 0 3 6 9];
Ne=zeros(1,length(SNR_dB));

for i=1:length(SNR_dB)
    SNR=10^(SNR_dB(i)/10);
    for t=1:Ts
        s=((sign(rand()-0.5))+1)/2; %create the "on"signal or "off" signal ."on"signal=1,"off" signal=0
        r=randn(2,1)./sqrt(2.*SNR); %it seems that it is noise
        if (s+r)>0.5
            s_hat=1;
        else
            s_hat=0;
        end
        if abs(s_hat-s)>0
            Ne(i)=Ne(i)+1;
        end
        y=Ne./Ts;
    end
end
Pe=zeros(1,5);
for i=1:5
    SNR=10^(SNR_dB(i)/10);
    Pe(i)=erfc(sqrt(SNR/2)/(2^0.5))/2;
end
semilogy(SNR_dB,y,'-r',SNR_dB,Pe,'-k')
```

I don't understand why can the noise be written as

> r=randn(2,1)./sqrt(2.*SNR)

,why do we need to write as `randn(2,1)./sqrt(2*SNR)` instead of `randn(1,1)/sqrt(2)`?Is anyone know about this?

Comment: Because that's how the noise power is adjusted to give the desired SNR.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is there any formula can prove this?

Comment: It's exactly the formula in that line of code: Power goes with the square of amplitude, and thus, you divide by the square root of the desired power factor. I honestly don't know what there is to explain about that...

Comment: i mean,SNR=signal power/noise power.so r=randn(2,1)./sqrt(2.*SNR)=randn(2,1)./sqrt(2.*(signal power/noise power)).why?why doesn't the  noise like SNR* randn(2,1)./sqrt(2)?

Comment: because it's S/N, not sqrt(N)/S. It's really just basic math applied to the definition of SNR.

Comment: basic math applied to the definition of SNR,but you can't explain,strange

Comment: I don't understand your criticism: you know that SNR is the ratio of signal power to noise power. Signal power is fixed in your code. You hence have to adjust the noise power. The higher the SNR gets, the lower the noise power hence must be. To scale the power linearly by a factor,  you need to scale the amplitude by the square root of the factor. That's all there is! I recommend you don't get defensive towards people trying to help you.

Comment: then why don't we write like (noise/sqrt(2)) *sqrt(SNR) instead of noise/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(SNR))?

Comment: for exmple ,now i have a noise,5/sqrt(2),and i want to let this noise become the noise in the SNR=1.5,that is SNR=3/2=(sqrt(3))^2 / (sqrt(2))^2.So i have to let 5/sqrt(2) become 1/sqrt(2).But if according to the formula,5/sqrt(2) *1/sqrt(SNR)=5/sqrt(2) *sqrt(2)/sqrt(3)=5/sqrt(3),and 5/sqrt(3) is not equal to  1/sqrt(2)

Comment: because that increases the noise power instead of decreasing it.

Comment: `randn(2,1)` creates a 2 by 1 array.  i don't see how it gets added to a single `s` and a single decision made on its value.

Comment: @MarcusMüller " I recommend you don't get defensive towards people trying to help you". I've noticed on multiple occasions you getting defensive Marcus when people are simply trying to better understand the provided answer. Please stop baiting people by providing snide remarks.

Comment: @Izzo I'm sorry to hear that; I don't want to convert this comment thread to a general discussion about why I don't agree with this, but refer to this discussion  specifically: I made what I thought to be a helpful comment ("you adjust the SNR that way") that addressed OP's question; OP asked for a formula, I pointed out it's the formula from the code, OP suggested incorrectly inverting that formula and I explained that it's an inversion, to which OP claimed I couldn't explain. I don't see where I got defensive here, sorry! Especially considering I actually explained the math in my comment?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but let me show how to generate a noisy signal of a desired SNR, assuming additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) model with fixed signal power.

First the basic definition of SNR (signal to noise ratio) is :
$$ \text{SNR} = \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_v^2} $$

where ${\sigma_x^2}$ is the signal power based on a WSS random signal model, and ${\sigma_v^2}$ is therefore the noise power (which I take here as white Gaussian noise).

SNR can also be defined in decibells:
$$ \text{SNR}_{dB} = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_v^2} \right) = 10 \log_{10}( \text{SNR}) $$

Assuming your signal power $\sigma_x^2$ is fixed, then you can adjust the noise power $\sigma_v^2$ to achieve a desired SNR with your AWGN signal model. The necessary noise power is found from required SNR as:

$$ \sigma_v^2 = \frac{ \sigma_x^2 }{ SNR } $$

Now, Matlab's built in Gaussian function **randn()** generates standard normal with zero mean and unit variance. Then to get a desired variance (hence noise power) you should scale it with the square root of the target power as shown:

```
sigx2  = 5.1;          % signal variance (power)
SNR    = 23 ;          % SNR = sigx^2 / sigv^2
sigv2  = sigx2 / SNR;  % noise variance (power)
N      = 1024;         % number of noise samples 
v = sqrt( sigv2 ) * randn(N,1); % White Gaussian noise
```

The reason why you multiply with the square root of the power (or variance) is based on the following property of the **variance** operator:

$$ \text{Var}(X) = \sigma_x^2  \implies \text{Var}(aX) = a^2 \sigma_x^2$$

Comment: because the randn() will produce the unit variance,that is ,$\sigma^2_{n}=1$,and now i know the SNR and the signal power,$\sigma^2_{x}$, is fixed.So actually,in this case,we have to let the $1$ become $\sigma^2_{n}$,and $\sigma^2_{n}= \frac{\sigma^2_{x}}{SNR}$ ,so we have to $1 \times \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_{x}}{SNR}}$,that's why we will write sqrt( sigv2 ) * randn(N,1) ,is my thinking right?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did ;-)

Comment: How would you adjust this for a signal represented in complex form?

Comment: Discrete-Random Signals and Statistical Signal Processing_THERRIEN gives quite detailed answers to complex random processing.